# Selenium + Safari - Webkit 300 error

Tags: java, selenium, safari

On my project I'm trying to enable automation tests using Selenium (3.4.0, also tried lower versions) on Mac with Safari. As Apple forums say, I'm using Technology preview for tests.

Safari starts okay, but all sites are failing with following error:

> Safari can't open page. The error is "Webkit encountered an internal error" (WebkitErrorDomain:300)

[image: Error example]

But in not-automation session everything opens correctly.

Here is how browser driver is initialized:

```
SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
safariOptions.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
caps.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOptions);
driver = new SafariDriver(caps);
```

Do you have any thoughts?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7084847?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: you are not alone :- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75417  .. seems it's a known bug

Comment: Yeah, I know. I asked question there.
But in that case, Technology Preview helped

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved? I can load websites using safari 'manually' no problem - but as soon as I try to browse to the same site using webdriver I get 'WebkitErrorDomain:300'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Safari does not support explicit waits anymore with 3.4.0 and safari 11. I faced the same issue and when i removed the explicit waits and used `Thread.sleep()` it seems to work fine. Although this not what i wanted but 300 error was gone.